# Bitmap take too much time to load

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, imageloader

I am trying to implement load bitmap in `ImageView`, but it is taking too much time to load. I have also used `ImageLoader` but it is only supports for url, it is not supports for bitmap, so how can I show bitmap instantly? Please help to solve it!

Show image using Image loader

For url I used this code

```
imgLoader.DisplayImage(mImage, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, imgProfile);
```

Comment: Use Picasso....

Comment: But it is not working on  bitmap!

Comment: This might help you, Resize it before setting in ImageView https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16874800/resize-bitmap-without-creating-new-bitmap/16874880#16874880

Comment: Thanks! but it's not working

Comment: Who said that _ImageLoader only supports for url, it is not supports for bitmap_ ? Use `SimpleImageLoadingListener` for imageloader you'll get override method of it and get bitmap object too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any `ImageLoader library` like [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide), [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Here is the snippet using `Glide`

```
Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(your_image_url_or_resource_id)
                .asBitmap()
                .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
                        // you can do something with loaded bitmap here

                        yourImageViewRef.setImageBitmap(resource);
                    }
                });
```

If you want to load image using url try this code

```
Glide.with(context).load(your_image_url_or_resource_id).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_icon)
                    .error(R.drawable.error_icon).into(yourImageViewRef);
```